# set AssetBrowser region height on keypress

Tags: 3d-view, object-mode, asset-browser

I cant seem to find a way to set an open region height in Blender using Python. I'm trying to set the height of the asset browser on keypress.

Is this possible through the Blender API?

```
for region in bpy.context.area.regions:
    if region.type == "ASSETS":
        print(region.height)
        break
```